# Is there a cordova-cli command to install app using the last build in the directory project?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, windows-phone, adb

Does anyone know how to run `cordova-cli` in order to install an app that been already built ?

Using `cordova run android` always cause the rebuild of the app. And its often useful but some times, its not necessary and we lost time.

Or maybe any one know the equivalent from `Adb` command line interface (android) and those for ios and windows phone (I don't know it yet) ?

Comment: @Remi you can try the following. Go to `bin` directory where the APK file is located and type the command `adb install <apk filename>`. Hope it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The run command has a --nobuild option which does exactly what you want.
Hooks are still executed though so when you have hooks it might still take some time for the app to start.

Example command for calling:
`cordova run android --nobuild`

**edit** to answer question below

You can see some documentation here: [link](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_tools.md.html#Android%20Shell%20Tool%20Guide)

For me the output shows it is skipping:

```
D:\Mobile>cordova run android --nobuild
Running command: D:\Mobile\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat --nobuild
Skipping build...
```

Comment: It don't work for me, and I can't find this option in the documentation. Have you got a link ? Are you sure about the spelling "--nobuild" ?